# How to import a package from a subdirectory in Django

Tags: python, django

I know there is a plenty of similar questions and answers but I really can't do that.
I splitted `views.py`, `models.py` and `forms.py` into several files in corresponding folders. So the folder structure is as follows:

```
myapp
  \__init__.py
  \admin.py
  \forms
     \__init__.py
     \my_forms.py
  \views
     \__init__.py
     \my_views.py
  \models
     \__init__.py
     \my_models.py
```

in the corresponding `__init__.py` files I added:

```
   from my_file import *
```

where `my_file` corresponds to `my_forms`, `my_views` and `my_models`.

And now I'm trying to import, say, forms from `my_views.py`:

```
   from myapp.forms import MyForm
```

As a result, I get the following error:

```
   No module named forms
```

Could somebody point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: python myapp's full path in PYTHONPATH as YardenST suggested

Comment: Thanks guys for your replies. No, I didn't add anything manually to PYTHONPATH. Am I supposed to add my modules manually to python path? I just wanted to use them as ordinary python modules. Could you please give me a link where a can read about modules in django and python path?

Comment: Would `from myapps import forms` followed by usage of `forms.MyForm` instead of just `MyForm` give an error too?

Comment: @MattiasNilsson, yes it also provides an error. I've tried different variants: `from myapp.my_forms import MyForm`, `from myproj.myapp.my_forms import MyForm`, `from my_forms import MyForm`. I even copied `my_forms.py` to the `/myapp/my_forms1.py` and tried `from myapp.my_forms1 import MyForm` from within `/myapp/views/my_views.py` but that didn't help, although it had worked when `my_views.py` was right in the `/myapp` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was my stupid mistake. In fact the directory structure was like that:

```
myapp
 |--__init__.py
 |--admin.py
 |--forms
     |--__init__.py
     |--myapp.py
 |--views
     |--__init__.py
     |--myapp.py
 |--models
     |--__init__.py
     |--myapp.py
```

That is I named forms, views and models file the same name as application name (for example, the application name was 'contacts', and the model file was 'contacts.py'). That led me to the errors in question.

So don't name inner files the same name as the application. Try to avoid the same names at all ;)

Thanks a lot for all who tried to help.